# Log4J copy a log file while application is logging

Tags: java, log4j

I have to add a method to a Java application to send to assistance its logs.
To send logs I mean to compress and send by email the log folder used by Log4J.
Sometimes this method fails due to a file lock, maybe because I want to compress something that log4j is writing. Is there something to unlock that file or stop log4j writing for a few?

Thanks

Comment: What is an exception when it fails? Can you just copy log file? This operation shall not be blocked by lock.

Comment: I will try to reproduce that exception than I will report it here.

Comment: Post your code as well. If you open file for reading, then you shall not experience lock problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

File lock issues will occur if you open some file in write mode though there is lock already hold. Opening the file in read mode only shall be safe. So you can copy the file elsewhere (to memory) and compress it to different location and then post it to helpdesk.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using the [`rollOver()`](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/RollingFileAppender.html#rollOver%28%29) method of the `RollingFileAppender` so that you force it to start a new file. Then you just collect the files that were closed and log4j is not using any more, and you don't risk losing any new logs in the mean time.

Comment: Ok but how to avoid to get the new file? Is there a method to find if a file is locked?

Comment: Mmm, not sure if log4j is designed to allow you to do that. Maybe someone will have another answer for it. Maybe you could just disable the appender and re-enable it again to avoid getting a new file. However, Leos's suggestion of copying the file makes sense too. It shouldn't be affected by the file lock.